Why is 阿卡西 written above 虚空 in the Genshin Impact sentence 因为在「虚空」之中，目前还没有你们的信息?
The following is a sentence from the game Genshin Impact (原神 in Chinese); you can watch the interaction at Douyin.


因为在「虚空」之中，目前还没有你们的信息。
Above 虚空 is written 阿卡西.

(Sorry it's hard to get a clear image: the font is incredibly small.)
I don't understand what 阿卡西 means nor why it's written there.  It seems like 虚空 here is used as a proper noun, so it might be an alternative name or something like that.  This is not my first time encountering this "written in small characters above a word" writing in Genshin Impact.
Question: Why is 阿卡西 written above 虚空 in the Genshin Impact sentence 因为在「虚空」之中，目前还没有你们的信息?

There is an article on Bilibili, 【原神3.0】虚空考据, that goes somewhat in depth into this:

四、虚空考据
虚空，在游戏中出现这个名词的时候，米哈游在其上方标注了“阿卡西”的字样。

阿卡西（Akasha）是梵文“空间”的意思。游戏内翻译为“虚空”也没有问题。看到这里，崩坏三的玩家可能很熟悉这个，虚空万藏就是个记录着知识的图书馆。
由Akasha这个词可以联想到阿卡西记录（Akashic records）。
“阿卡西记录（Akashic records，又称为“生命之书”、“阿卡西档案”） 阿卡西（阿卡夏）是梵文，它的意思是“以太”或者宇宙的原始能量。阿卡西记录是传说中的宇宙生命信息数据库，是一种记载着每时每刻所产生的一切思想，言语和行动的宇宙通用档案系统，是一种储存于“以太”之中的神秘知识的集合。”——来自百度百科。
以太（Aether）这个词同样也是主角之一的“空”的翻译。空的翻译也是Aether。在亚里士多德的概念中，以太是天空（星空）的组成部分。
重新说回阿卡西记录，阿卡西记录是一种记载知识的东西，这一点和虚空重合。注意，虚空并不是虚空系统。同样，阿卡西记录是记载而并非发现，这与虚空也是重合的。虚空的知识是通过学者上传的。

Akasha (阿卡西) literally means void (虚空), so there seems to be interchangeability between the terms. In Chinese 虚空 may not be interpreted so specifically, it appears that the creators have tacked 阿卡西 on top to specify what exactly it is they are referring to here.

指"空間".
虚空(佛学, 梵语) - 虚無一物又可容納萬物的空間. https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%99%9B%E7%A9%BA_(%E4%BD%9B%E6%95%99)
